# Merge multiple flv files?

Tags: command-line, video, adobe-flash

What tool in Linux can I use to merge multiple flv files ? Files are already in order, just put them altogether seamlessly

Comment: Do you want a GUI or a commandline tool? For the first case you could try `avidemux`

Comment: @student command line, I will create a script

Comment: Then you can try `ffmpeg`

Comment: Do all files have the same resolution and the same audio encoding + same bitrate?

Comment: @student yes, just take it as video segments downloaded from video site like youtube

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't test the following yet, so see it just as some hints.

You could use `ffmpeg`. From the manual

```
* You can put many streams of the same type in the output:

               ffmpeg -i test1.avi -i test2.avi -vcodec copy -acodec copy -vcodec copy -acodec copy test12.avi -newvideo -newaudio

       In addition to the first video and audio streams, the resulting output file
       test12.avi will contain the second video and the second audio stream found in the
       input streams list.

       The "-newvideo", "-newaudio" and "-newsubtitle" options have to be specified
       immediately after the name of the output file to which you want to add them.
```

You can also use `mencoder` for example:

```
mencoder -forceidx -ovc copy -oac pcm -o output.flv input1.flv input2.flv
```

Another option is maybe [`flvcat`](http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/vnc2flv/index.html#flvcat.py).

You could also try `avidemux-cli`.

Answer (score 1):

You can check [this FAQ](http://ffmpeg.org/faq.html#How-can-I-concatenate-video-files_003f) from the FFmpeg website.

It seems to be a matter of using the "concat" filter or the "concat" protocol. I never tried the former, so I can't help you on that one, and I tried the latter only with MPEG files, so perhaps a few adjustments are needed when using FLV files.