# Merging flv files causes a massive size increase

Tags: size, merge, mencoder

I have 3 flv files which I wish to merge. I used the answer in this post:

[Merge multiple flv files?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45870/merge-multiple-flv-files)

which suggested this option:

mencoder -forceidx -ovc copy -oac pcm -o output.flv input1.flv input2.flv

It seems to have worked except that the merged file is 400meg in size whereas the original 3 files were about 33meg each.

Is this expected? Is there a way to join the 3 files without the massive increase in size?

Comment: I can't explain the massive increase in size. Check my answer for a solution using ffmpeg.

Comment: Hmmm, with mencoder, isn't that actually making an AVI file (but with a `.flv` suffix)?

Answer (score 1):

Create a file `mylist.txt` with all the files you want to have concatenated in the following form:

```
    # this is a comment
    file '/path/to/file1'
    file '/path/to/file2'
    file '/path/to/file3'
```

Then you can encode your files with:

```
    ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt -c copy output
```

Edit: You may need to compile `ffmpeg` from source to get a recent enough version.

Source:
http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/How%20to%20concatenate%20(join,%20merge)%20media%20files

Comment: thanks. Unfortunately I am getting:

Unknown input format: 'concat'

Comment: okay, wait. I think I have an old ffmpeg version

Comment: confirmation that it works except you do need ffmpeg 1.1 which I had to install from source. Even the repository holding the latest latest for Debian only had 1.0.1